# Symfony ux-react: npm run build create 3 errors

Tags: reactjs, symfony

I created my project in Symfony 7.0.5 and I would like to add React-UX to my project. I followed this YouTube tutorial: https://youtu.be/jPi9HcP7fU8?si=iG5PjIC43wJBz2an (french video).
When I run `npm run build`, I get these 3 errors:

```
PS C:\wamp64\www\freelance-management-system> npm run build      

> build
> encore production --progress

Running webpack ...

99% done plugins FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin ERROR  Failed to compile with 3 errors                                                                                                                                                                   
                                    13:52:18

Module build failed: Module not found:
"./assets/app.js" contains a reference to the file "@symfony/ux-react".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

"./assets/bootstrap.js" contains a reference to the file "@symfony/stimulus-bundle".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

"./assets/react/controllers/Hello.jsx" contains a reference to the file "react".
This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

Entrypoint app = runtime.869f9e00.js app.92a5ef62.css app.67bc40d7.js
webpack compiled with 3 errors
```

Here is my app.js:

```
import { registerReactControllerComponents } from '@symfony/ux-react';
import './bootstrap.js';
/*
 * Welcome to your app's main JavaScript file!
 *
 * This file will be included onto the page via the importmap() Twig function,
 * which should already be in your base.html.twig.
 */
import './styles/app.css';

console.log('This log comes from assets/app.js - welcome to AssetMapper! ');

registerReactControllerComponents(require.context('./react/controllers', true, /\.(j|t)sx?$/));
```

Here is my bootstrap.js:

```
import { startStimulusApp } from '@symfony/stimulus-bundle';

const app = startStimulusApp();
// register any custom, 3rd party controllers here
// app.register('some_controller_name', SomeImportedController);
```

Here is my React controller:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function (props) {
    return <div>Hello {props.fullName}</div>;
}
```

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or subdirectory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    .enableReactPreset()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // configure Babel
    // .configureBabel((config) => {
    //     config.plugins.push('@babel/a-babel-plugin');
    // })

    // enables and configure @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = '3.23';
    })

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    //.enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment if you use React
    .enableReactPreset()

    // uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
    // requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
    //.enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    //.autoProvidejQuery()
    .enablePostCssLoader()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.17.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.0",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^4.0.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.18",
        "core-js": "^3.23.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.35",
        "postcss-loader": "^7.3.4",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
        "webpack": "^5.74.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.15.0"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress"
    }
}
```

Here is my composer.json:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.2",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.11",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.3",
        "doctrine/orm": "^3.1",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.3",
        "phpstan/phpdoc-parser": "^1.26",
        "symfony/asset": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/asset-mapper": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/console": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/doctrine-messenger": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/form": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/intl": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/mime": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/notifier": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/process": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/stimulus-bundle": "^2.16",
        "symfony/string": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/translation": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/ux-react": "^2.16",
        "symfony/ux-turbo": "^2.16",
        "symfony/validator": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^2.1",
        "symfony/yaml": "7.0.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "php-http/discovery": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php82": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd",
            "importmap:install": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "7.0.*"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^7.0",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "7.0.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "7.0.*"
    }
}
```

And here is my file tree: [File tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bqg8e.png)